# Levenstein distance, multiple paths

Tags: c++, levenshtein-distance, damerau-levenshtein

***Edit:*** TL;DR version: how to get all possible backtraces for Damerau–Levenshtein distance between two words? I'm using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm in order to compute distance, and trivial backtrace algorithm (illustrated below) in order to reconstruct corrections list.

***More details below:***

Just got stuck with optimal string alignment (sort of Damerau–Levenshtein distance) while trying to get a complete set of possible alignments.

Goal is to align 2 strings for further comparison in auto-suggestions algorithm. Particularly, I'd like to ignore insertions past the end of 1st word.

The problem that in some cases multiple "optimal" alignments is possible, e.g.

```
align("goto", "go to home")

1) go to
   go to home

2) go t   o
   go to home
```

Unfortunately, mine implementation finds second variant only, while I need both or 1st one.

I've tried to perform some kind of A* or BFS path finding, but it looks like cost computation matrix is "tuned" for (2) variant only. There is screenshot below where I can find red path, but it looks like there is no green path:
[image: screenshot]

However, someone made a web demo which implements exactly what I want: 
[image: web demo]

What I'm missing here?

Perhaps my implementation is too long to post it here, so there is a link to github: https://github.com/victor-istomin/incrementalSpellCheck/blob/f_improvement/spellCheck.hpp

Distance implementation is located in optimalStringAlignementDistance() and optimalStringAlignmentBacktrace() methods.